# Facebook fb-login not redirecting back

Tags: facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, fbml

I want to authenticate the user using facebook login credentials. Everything works, except for the fact that it does not redirect to the redirect_uri specified which I require to capture the signed_request. Any help is hugely appreciated.

Below is what I have

```
#fb-root
%script{:src => "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"}
:javascript
  FB.init({
    appId:'my_client_id_from_the_app_i_created', cookie:true,
    status:true, xfbml:true
  });
%fb:login-button{:perms => "publish_stream", :redirect_uri => "#{facebook_signin_url}"}
  Login using your facebook account.
```

Comment: where does it redirect you instead?

Comment: Does nothing. Just closes the popup window. Nothing in rails log either.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to use:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/

Also, I'm not familiar with Ruby-on-Rails, but

where do you get **facebook_signin_url**?

and what is the # in the **redirect_uri**?