# Facebook fb-login not redirecting back

Tags: facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, fbml

I want to authenticate the user using facebook login credentials. Everything works, except for the fact that it does not redirect to the redirect_uri specified which I require to capture the signed_request. Any help is hugely appreciated.

Below is what I have

```
#fb-root
%script{:src => "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"}
:javascript
  FB.init({
    appId:'my_client_id_from_the_app_i_created', cookie:true,
    status:true, xfbml:true
  });
%fb:login-button{:perms => "publish_stream", :redirect_uri => "#{facebook_signin_url}"}
  Login using your facebook account.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook fb-login not redirecting back](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566545/facebook-fb-login-not-redirecting-back)

Answer (score 3):

Since you mention signed_request I assume that you are building a canvas or page tab app.

If so, I don't recommend that you use the login-button.

Rather, just redirect to the OAuth Dialog.

This creates a much better experience for the user.

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/#auth for step by step instructions.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are using the fb canvas the application will POST back to
   the url set in the canvas url setting, or you can set the window
   location using <%= fb_login_button('window.location =
   "/users/link_user_accounts";')%>
2. redirect_uri is not a valid fb:login-button option, so means nothing to fb. If you are not using the canvas and this is a website, and you want to redirect after login, use the onlogin option(instead of the redirect_uri) to call javascript to post to the location you desire. Check out how this is done in the authlogic-facebook-connect gem: https://github.com/kalasjocke/authlogic_facebook_connect/blob/master/lib/authlogic_facebook_connect/helper.rb